# Rotating ~90° using Two-Point Equidistant projection with Proj4

Tags: raster, r, coordinate-system, proj

I'm trying to rotate a tif raster in `R` using `Proj4`'s [Two-Point Equidistant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-point_equidistant_projection) projection - I think the only way to rotate spatial geometries to custom angles.  But I'm finding the operation gets very slow approaching 90°, and in fact fails for that angle (possibly 2 separate issues).  This demonstrates:

```
require(raster)
require(rgdal)
# demo raster
r <- disaggregate(raster(volcano[1:60,1:60]), 4)
extent(r) <- c(-5,5,-5,5)
crs(r) <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"

# proj4 two-point equidistant rotate transformations
tpeqd_45 <- CRS("+proj=tpeqd +lat_1=2 +lon_1=-2 +lat_2=-2 +lon_2=2 +a=6371000 +units=m +no_defs")
tpeqd_80 <- CRS("+proj=tpeqd +lat_1=1.9 +lon_1=0.35 +lat_2=-1.9 +lon_2=-0.35 +a=6371000 +units=m +no_defs")
tpeqd_90 <- CRS("+proj=tpeqd +lat_1=2 +lon_1=0 +lat_2=-2 +lon_2=-0 +a=6371000 +units=m +no_defs")

system.time(r_45 <- projectRaster(r, crs=tpeqd_45))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.350   0.051   0.404 
par(mfcol = c(1,2)); image(r, asp=T); image(r_45, asp=T)
```

[image]

```
system.time(r_80 <- projectRaster(r, crs=tpeqd_80))
   user  system elapsed 
  3.857   0.879   4.877
system.time(r_90 <- projectRaster(r, crs=tpeqd_90))
Error in if (value[1] != nrow(x) | value[2] != ncol(x)) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
In `dim<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c(nr, nc)) :
  NAs introduced by coercion to integer range
```

Note the increasing time to process for 80°.  For a 10x bigger raster this crashes my Macbook.  Does anyone know if this is a problem in the math for this projection and/or if there is any other way to rotate these in R?

Comment: Possible workaround: use oblique Mercator instead, center point and alpha but set gamma to 0. omerc also supports definition by two points, but may reorient so north is "up" or use gamma to set that. There's also a no_rot parameter that might work.

Comment: Nice suggestion. I've tried with e.g. `+proj=omerc +lat_0=0 +lonc=0 +alpha=45`, with various alphas and `+no_rot` argument but also no luck.

Comment: Maybe try switching to +gamma?

Comment: Yes that does start to work. Unclear how the params alpha and gamma interrelate though: I seem to have similar issues to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34294877/proj4-oblique-mercator-giving-strange-results-when-alpha-is-between-90-and-270-i). I'm working through it..

Comment: Alpha is applied near the beginning within the mathematics of the projection. Gamma is applied at the end to re-orient the rotated cylinder--often used to have geodetic/true north "up" at the center of the projection.

Comment: There are *loads* of ways to rotate spatial features (including rasters) by means of reprojection.  One of the most natural and computationally simple is to declare the input to be in a polar azimuthal projection: just change its central meridian by the negative of the amount you want to rotate everything.

Comment: @whuber thanks but I tried finding a proj4 azimuthal to do this but [thought I drew a blank](http://www.remotesensing.org/geotiff/proj_list/azimuthal_equidistant.html).  Do you know which parameter would that be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Using an azimuthal projection makes it easy to rotate a raster** (or any geographic layer, for that matter).  Just pretend the data are in a polar azimuthal projection and change its central longitude by the negative of the angle.

Here, for example, is a bare-bones `R` function illustrating the procedure.  Its arguments are a raster object `x`, an angle of rotation `a` (in degrees counterclockwise), and an optional output resolution.

- The first line creates a copy of `x` and tells the software to interpret the coordinates in the copy as if they were in an azimuthal equidistant projection (at the north pole) with a reference longitude of zero.
- The second line reprojects the copy to an equidistant azimuthal coordinate system with a different reference longitude.

**The net effect is the desired rotation,** as the maps in the figure show.  (The resolution was also refined in the rotated images to verify the effect of the `resolution` argument.)

```
library(raster)
rotate <- function(x, angle=0, resolution=res(x)) {
  y <- x; crs(y) <- "+proj=aeqd +ellps=sphere +lat_0=90 +lon_0=0"
  projectRaster(y, res=resolution, 
                     crs=paste0("+proj=aeqd +ellps=sphere +lat_0=90 +lon_0=", -angle))
}
```

As an example, I created a raster and rotated it by various angles around its (0,0) coordinate (at its center).

[image: Figure]

Notice that *it is irrelevant what coordinate system is actually used in the input raster.* However, the output will be tagged with this artificial rotated azimuthal equidistant system.  You can always re-specify it if you want, but in most applications this likely would not be meaningful.

The only limitation to this method is that coordinates in the input raster must be valid coordinates in the azimuthal system.  This will rarely be a problem, but if it is, first shrink the coordinates, perform the rotation, and then expand the coordinates.

Here is the `R` code to create the maps.

```
x <- raster(matrix(1:(15*25), nrow=15), xmn=-1000, xmx=1000, ymn=-1000, ymx=1000)
plot(x, main="Original")
for (a in c(45, 90, 150))
  plot(rotate(x, a, resolution=10), main=paste("Rotated by", format(a, ndigits=0)))
```

---

This method, although convenient to code, is not blazingly fast: for some purposes (where resampling is not needed, for instance) you can do much better by applying a rotation matrix directly to the underlying data.  But it's not too slow, either.  On my system a rotation of a 600 by 1000 raster takes under 3 seconds:

```
> x <- raster(matrix(1:(600*1000), nrow=600), xmn=-1000, xmx=1000, ymn=-1000, ymx=1000)
> system.time(rotate(x, 33))

user  system elapsed 
2.73    0.17    2.90
```

Comment: Awesome thanks @whuber.  What would you recommend as the best reference for Proj4? Preferably something outlining all valid arguments for a particular projection..  I've been trawling through the [official manual](ftp://ftp.remotesensing.org/proj/OF90-284.pdf) and [remotesensing](http://www.remotesensing.org/geotiff/proj_list/) but not found anything particularly helpful.

Comment: Great answer!  You can also use rasterImage with its angle and interpolation arguments, but you need to correct for the rotation centre (bottom left corner).

Comment: @whuber, thank you for your answer; however, I have question,  so I am trying to rotate a raster file with a defined `proj4string(r) <- "+proj=utm +zone=15 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"`, do I need to change something in your `rotate` function? I am interested in keeping the same `proj4string`.

Comment: @Perro You shouldn't need to change anything.  The projected raster will not have an appropriate projection string associated with it, though, nor should it--after all, after this rotation it won't be in the same projection as the input raster.  It looks like the comments after the figure fully explain this.

Comment: @whuber thank your your response. I know understand what you are saying about the input and out projection system. Based on that, I was wondering if it is possible to rotate this image that I have (lets say 90deg) without affecting its projection system?

Comment: @Perro No, because the rotation changes the projection.

Comment: @whuber so I posted a question regarding [Image orientation/projection issues in R](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/296824/image-orientation-projection-issues-in-r?noredirect=1#comment477544_296824), and I was wondering if you could take a look at it and let me know what you think.