# Azimuthal Equidistant Projection - Rotate projection

Tags: javascript, coordinate-system

I am using Azimuthal Equidistant Projection to plot points in a map being drawn in an Android application.

The origin is the centre of the map.

I have the formulas from [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AzimuthalEquidistantProjection.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945814/formulas-in-azimuthal-equidistant-projection). I am getting expected results.

Simplified version of the code being used by me in JavaScript:

```
// Add functions to Math
if (!Math.toRadians)
    Math.toRadians = function(angledeg) {
        return angledeg * Math.PI / 180;
    };
if (!Math.toDegrees)
    Math.toDegrees = function(anglerad) {
        return anglerad * 180 / Math.PI;
    };

/* Mean radius of Earth (in metres)*/
const WGS_1984_R = 6370997;

/* Function to convert geodetic coordinates to Azimuthal Equidistant Projection projection (cartesian metres)*/
function convertGeodeticToAEP(longitude, latitude, longitudeOrigin, latitudeOrigin) {
    var deltaLongitudes = Math.toRadians(longitude - longitudeOrigin),
            cosDeltaLongitudes = Math.cos(deltaLongitudes),
            cosLatitude = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(latitude)),
            sinLatitude = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(latitude)),
            cosLatitudeOrigin = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(latitudeOrigin)),
            sinLatitudeOrigin = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(latitudeOrigin)),
            // Angular distance from the centre
            c = Math.acos(sinLatitudeOrigin * sinLatitude + cosLatitudeOrigin * cosLatitude * cosDeltaLongitudes),
            k = c == 0 ? 0 : c / Math.sin(c),
            x = k * cosLatitude * Math.sin(deltaLongitudes) * WGS_1984_R,
            y = k * (cosLatitudeOrigin * sinLatitude - sinLatitudeOrigin * cosLatitude * cosDeltaLongitudes) * WGS_1984_R;
    return {x: x, y: y};
}
```

What would be the formulas to rotate the projection by a given angle, from the origin? Say modify the function to include an additional parameter for angle of rotation and then modify the output accordingly...

Comment: @whuber Unlike the answer (http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/183175/rotating-90-using-two-point-equidistant-projection-with-proj4) mentioned, I am not using R or Proj4. So that does not answer my question...

Comment: You asked for 'formulas".  If you intended to ask for something else, then please edit your post.