# Angular rotation using Proj4, for local coordinate system

Tags: coordinate-system, javascript, proj, mercator, proj4js

I have a polygon feature on map to which I need to transform the coordinates to local coordinate system with respect to new origin while keeping the same datum.

So far using the **Proj4** library and by defining the custom map origin I could able to re-project/transform my global coordinates to local as follows

`+proj=etmerc +lat_0=52.481392 +lon_0=13.355795 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs` --Using this Proj4 definition

**Here in the image you can see the marker with name "New Origin" is the one I want to keep at center and transform the coordinates of highlighted polygons to local coordinate system**
[image: Here in the image you can see the marker with name "New Origin" is the one I want to keep at center and transform the coordinates of highlighted polygons to local coordinate system]

**These are the original coordinates of selected polygons**
[image: These are the original coordinates]

**These are the transformed coordinates of same polygon w.r.t. new map origin**
[image]

What I am looking forward now is the case of rotated map origin, as of now the current map origin is facing northwards i.e. to north pole, which I need to be rotated by around 90 degrees. Ideally this rotation should effect coordinates of the polygon (as those -ve now may get positive and vice versa).

`+proj=omerc +lat_0=52.481392 +lonc=13.355795 +alpha=90.0 +k=1.0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +no_uoff +gamma=90.0 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs` --New definition I am trying

Regarding the same, I found [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/279763/correct-projection-proj-4-string-to-rotate-map) question helpful and thought to try the *Oblique Mercator* projection, however the results are not changing when I did the 90 degree rotation for [alpha and gamma](https://proj4.org/operations/projections/omerc.html?highlight=oblique)

Comment: Try using only alpha or only gamma, not both.

Comment: @mkennedy I tried those combination, but the results are still the same i.e. I am still getting the same coordinates as if no rotation is applied.

Comment: After setting +alpha to 90 degree I am getting following changes in coordinates
[-7.6953274440020305, -34.018725226408954]
[-2.501843264326451, -38.56306296658011]
[12.448381118476393, -19.840427535785217]
[5.318901741877199, -14.513489642501089]
So the coordinates are changed but (noticeably on X axis), but it doesn't seems like it changed to the effect of 90 degree.

Comment: Try omitting +no_uoff which should convert the definition from a natural origin case to a center version so the rotation may make more sense.

Comment: If you don't specify both `alpha` and `gamma` it sets the missing one to the explicitly defined one.  Set the `+gamma=0` to work in the rotated coordinates, otherwise, gamma=alpha will keep your coordinates aligned with the original azimuth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally achieved this by referring [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17410809/how-to-calculate-rotation-in-2d-in-javascript) which have the rotation method for passed coordinates with respect to the origin. So in above case I had to transform the map origin to local coordinate system, and then pass the respective polygon coordinates as follow,

```
let transformedOrigin = proj4(localProjection, [originY, originX]);
let rotatedLocalCoords = this.rotate(transformedOrigin[0], transformedOrigin[1], polygonCoord[x], polygonCoord[y], -90);
```

And the rotated method is as follows,

```
rotate: function (cx, cy, x, y, angle) {
  let radians = (Math.PI / 180) * angle;
  let cos = Math.cos(radians);
  let sin = Math.sin(radians);
  let nx = (cos * (x - cx)) + (sin * (y - cy)) + cx;
  let ny = (cos * (y - cy)) - (sin * (x - cx)) + cy;
  return [nx, ny];
}
```